# How to display the normal values of a face?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to know the orientation of a certain face by knowing the z vector(direction vector) of its normal. How do I let Blender display the values of the normal of a face?

Answer (score 5):

You can toggle the on in the Mesh Display panel:
[image: Mesh Display Panel]